# If-else statement trouble

Tags: list, if-statement

My project uses an if-else statement to determine if a random image from a list of images matches to an image in another list. I'm trying to find a piece of code that will allow me to set the if-else statement so when it asks: if randomImage == list[?]. In the question mark I need code that will go through the entire list and see if the randomImage matches from ANY of the elements in the list. Here's a snippet of code: [trash[randomTrash] generate a random image from the list trash. I need it so it checks if the random image of trash is equal to an image in another list. It needs to go through recycle list and determine if an element is equal to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbt8F.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an easier way to do this depending on your project specifics, but you should be able to use a for loop that loops through each element in your list.

```
for (int element = 0; element < list.length; element++) {
   if (randomImage == list[element]) {
      // randomImage matches with an element in the list. Assuming you are using some boolean variable 'match' which is initialized to be false.
      match = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's really helpful if you tag the language you're using, so people know how exactly to address the issue in particular.

The most common and straightforward approach you would see is looping through the whole list by index, and comparing each image to the one from it, and that's a solid working one.

If you're on a language supporting list comprehension you could take an approach similar to this,

```
 [x for x if x==image...]
```

then check if the list is empty for your if/else condition.

Please let us know in particular if it's something more specific you're looking for.

Comment: I tried adding the loop, but it just makes the score counter messed up and doesn't give the correct output. For a little background, my app is a sorting game where I sort images of trash into either a recycle or compost bin. There's an image on the screen that generates a random image from a list of images of trash. When the random trash image generates, the user has to click on either the recycle or compost bin. The if-else statement is used to determine when the user clicks on one of the bins, if the random generated trash is equal to any of the images of trash inside the list.