# Messed up point counter from trying to sort random images

Tags: list, image, if-statement, code.org

I have a list that contains 8 images on total. From index value 0-3 are images of recyclable items, and from index value 4-7 are images of compost items. I have 2 images of bins on the UI: a picture of a recycle bin and a picture of a compost bin. I have another blank image on the screen that presents a random image from the list of 8 images. I'm using an if-else statement when you click on either of the bins to determine if the random image matches with the bins. For example, if the random image is list[0], it would be a recyclable item. Thus, if the user clicks on the recycle bin, it should add a point. However, if the random image is list[0] and the user clicks on the compost bin, it should subtract a point. My if-else statement is not working accordingly. Here's the full chunk of code. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz4Ev.png) Heres a picture of the UI. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNyyq.png)

Comment: What language is this? Please add the appropriate language tag. Please also post your actual code _as [formatted text](/help/formatting)_, not an image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If-else statement trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821305/if-else-statement-trouble)

Answer (score 0):

You should separately create a randomTrash variable and use it in the if statement to check. Like so;

```
var randomTrash = trash[randomNumber(0,7)];
onEvent("recycle","click", function(){

if(randomTrash == trash[0] ...){
  
  points = points + 1;
  ...
}
})
```

Comment: It adds 1 point every time you click on the compost bin, and deducts 1 point every time you click on the recycle bin.

Comment: Is that your problem or just describing to me how your program works?

Comment: That's the problem after i added the new variable.

Comment: Oh ok, then It needs to change every time you click either recycle or compost bin. You can do it by adding randomTrash = trash[randomNumber(0,7)]; right after your if-else statement both onEvent. It might work.